# Reading lines from text files in Java

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to read product information from some text files. In my text file I have products and their information.

This is my file:

```
Product1:

ID: 1232
Name: ABC35

InStock: Yes
```

As you see, some products have blank lines in their product information, and I was wondering if there is any good way to determine if the line is blank, then read the next line.

How can I accomplish that? If the reading line is blank, then read the next line.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Underneath the question area when you were typing there was a proofreading area. It's well-worth using that area and, before clicking Ask Question, cleaning up typos and such. With respect, the question <s>is</s> was *riddled* with typos that could easily have been fixed prior to posting. *Edit*: "Dr TJ" (no relation) and I have fixed them for you on this occasion, but for next time...

Comment: Thank you, iam new to the site and will defintly consider that for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I may be misunderstanding. Assuming you have a `BufferedReader`, your main processing loop would be:

```
br = /* ...get the `BufferedReader`... */;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.length() == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // Process the non-blank lines from the input here
}
```

---

**Update**: Re your comment:

> For example if I want to read the line after name, if that line is blank or empty, I want to read the line after that.

The above is how I would structure my processing loop, but if you prefer, you can simply use a function that returns the next non-blank line:

```
String readNonBlankLine(BufferedReader br) {
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

That returns `null` at EOF like `readLine` does, or returns the next line that doesn't consist entirely of whitespace. Note that it doesn't strip whitespace from the line (my processing loop above does, because usually when I'm doing this, I want the whitespace trimmed off lines even if they're not blank).

Comment: T.J. Crowder - For example if I want to read the line after name, if that line is blank or empty, I want to read the line after that.

Comment: @Danne: I've added a further example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this should definitly work. One more question. I was wondering if a product property like Name is spread over two or more lines. How can I determine if to read all the lines that belongs to Name and when the readLine() comes to InStock line then read those properties. Any idea?

Comment: @Danne: I would build up the object in memory, e.g. in a `Product` object you define. Remember the labelling token ("ID", "Name", "InStock", etc.) you've seen most recently and in the case of a multi-line name, just append to the name you've previously saved. So when you see `Name: foo`, you'd do `p.name = line.substring(toklen+1).trim();` (where `toklen` is the length of the token; `4` in the case of "name") and if the next line doesn't start with a different token, it's `p.name += " " + line.trim();` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop over all the lines in the file, and if one is blank, ignore it.

To test if it's blank, just compare it to the empty String:

```
if (line.equals(""))
```

This won't work with lines with spacing characters (space, tabs), though. So you might want to do

```
if (line.trim().equals(""))
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I was wondering what if a product name is spread over two or more lines, how can I determine that? Read the lines that belongs to name and then read the lines that belongs to other properties.

Comment: Then you would have to read each line, determine if it's the start of a new property, and if not, append the content of the line to the previous property. But such a file format is really a bad choice: it's harder to parse than necessary. Are you forced to handle those possibilities, or couldn't you simply decide that this should never happen?

Comment: Iam unfortunately forced to handle those possibilites, do you have any idea if any body else have done something line this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure hundreds of developers have done this kind of thing, but they've done it for their own proprietary bizarre format, and you won't be able to find anything suited to your own format.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the length of the line:

```
 String line;
 while((line= bufreader.readLine()) != null)
    if (line.trim().length() != 0)
       return line;
```